# Как выбрать из OSM улицы целиком используя Nominatim?

Tags: google-maps-api, openstreetmap, leafletjs, geocoding, geojson

У меня задача: зная координаты точки получить geojson ближайшей улицы, чтобы в последствии "нарисовать" улицу на карте.

Для этого пробую использовать Nominatim reverse Api.
Пример запроса: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=45.198684&lon=33.396035&addressdetails=1&polygon_geojson=1&zoom=16

Но в ответ получаю только отрезок улицы (в osm дороги разбиты на отрезки).

Пробую сразу делать второй запрос к Nominatim используя уже полное название улицы: "Симферопольская улица, Евпатория, городской округ Евпатория, Республика Крым". В ответ получаю набор отрезков этой улицы. Но заметил, что возвращаются не все отрезки улицы. Возникают "дыры":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посоветуйте, как правильно решать мою задачу?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать другой сервис типа OpenStreetMap (OSM) data. Пример кода  для получения геометрии всех дорог с именем "Симферопольская улица" в Евпатории:

```
import osmnx as ox

place_name = "Евпатория"
street_name = "Симферопольская улица"

graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
streets = ox.streets_from_place(place_name, retain_all=True)
```